# Why does React's onClick function require unique syntax? compared to other event triggers?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have begun to notice an unusual pattern. Any onClick event requires the syntax to be 
`onClick={() => «name of function»}`.
I have also spent time researching as to the reason why onClick seems to be the only event handler which requires the paranthesis, but all I can find are articles that explain *what to do* but not *why it works that way*. OnChange and other events do not require that same syntax, but they are all types of events. All advice and explanations are welcome.

Comment: I think [this part of the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html) is a great read to get a grip of all the different function types in JavaScript.

Comment: I understand the scoping, but I don't understand why onClick runs all the time when the parenthesis are not included. Other events, such as onChange do not require the parenthesis, but onClick does. But, what makes onClick require the paranthesis?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the function is properly bound, or is an arrow function, you can write `onChange={myFunction}` just as well as `onClick={myFunction}`.

Comment: Event handlers such as `onClick`, `onChange` etc need to be given a reference to a function. It doesn't matter if this reference is an arrow function that you create in-line (like you describe) or if it's a variable.

Comment: [Why is my function being called every time the component renders?](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-functions.html#why-is-my-function-being-called-every-time-the-component-renders), Is this what you're asking?

Comment: Sort of. I guess I had a misunderstanding of the references being passed and the function call. Sorry for not realizing that. But, thanks to the answers, I understand this a lot better; event handlers require references not function calls. Whoops.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

onClick doesn't require "the parenthesis". That's an **arrow function**, it's one of several ways of  passing an event handler to the component.

This is one way:

```
onClick={this.nameOfFunction} // In this case, you need to bind the this in the constructor.
```

This is another way:

```
onClick={this.nameOfFunction.bind(this)}
```

And this is another one:

```
onClick={() => this.nameOfFunction()}
```

But, as the docs says: "Using an arrow function in render creates a new function each time the component renders, which may have performance implications (see below)."

Answer (score 2):

Usually, when it comes to React components, the functions probably are using the `this.setState` method or even accessing to the component props (eg: `this.props`), so the methods need to use the right `this` keyword (which is dynamically bound).

The **arrow functions** are great for this purpose, they provide a nice syntax and also a [they don't have its own `this`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions), which means that the `this` that are used inside them are the same as the parent `this`.

So when you need to pass an event handler to a component without changing the **meaning** of the `this` keyword you can do the following:

### Defining your event handler as an `arrow function`

```
eventHandler = () => console.log(this.props)
...
onClick={this.eventHandler}
```

### Wrapping your event handler with an `arrow function`

```
onClick={() => this.eventHandler()}
```

### Using the `Function.prototype.bind` method

```
onClick={this.eventHandler.bind(this)}
```

**Note:** Is important to mention that if you want to pass an **eventHandler** to `onClick`, it should be a reference, otherwise your event handler will be executed **everytime the component is rendered**.